# What is the 'normal' CPU temp?

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-load

What is the 'normal' CPU temp should be?

My CPU temperature normally (when the system is idle) remains around 60C and often jumps up to 80c or more.

```
dino@mika:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +57.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dino@mika:~$ **acpi -t**
Thermal 0: ok, 29.8 degrees C
Thermal 1: active, 62.0 degrees C
```

What are Thermal 0 and Thermal 1 temperatures here?

Comment: Are you running an HP Pavilion?

Comment: No, SAMSUNG Series 3 300E5A (Intel® Core™ i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 | Memory: 4GB)

Comment: Have a similar problem with an HP.  No solution.  For a kick, google backng your HP motherboard. The graphics chip solder joints fracture, and the device needs to be reflowed to make it work again.  I have done this process twice, and may need to do it again.

Comment: Thanks for stopping-by anyway, buddy. Any idea about Thermal 0 and 1? How am I to understand these figures?

Comment: Are you using Psensor?  If so, click on sensor preferences, and it may show a better description of what the sensors are

Comment: I just installed psensor. :) This is great! Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The T-junction max for an i5-2450M is listed by intel as 100C

http://ark.intel.com/products/53452/Intel-Core-i5-2450M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz

which would tend to suggest its normal operating temp was quite "hot".

Comment: Any possible solution for this over-heating?

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say is that 80C is probably a normal temperature for the T-junction on that CPU, i.e. the CPU itself isn't overheating. If it is causing a problem elsewhere in the device, then adjusting the thermal limits lower in the BIOS may help (if applicable, sorry i don't have that laptop and have no idea what options are available).
You may want to consider automatic frequency scaling, so that the CPU isn't running at max. I have had a great deal of use out of TLP in the past:
http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

Comment: So I don't have to worry too much about this 'issue'. Thank you very much indeed for your answer and the comment.